# C# SQLCommand does not work

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

I have a WebService with the following Method:

```
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod]
    public string Login(string passwort, string email, string firma)
    {
        return LoginHelper.Login(passwort, email, firma);
    }
```

My LoginHelper code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebService1
{
    public class LoginHelper
    {
        public static string Login(string passwort, string email, string firma)
        {
            string userName = "";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Yeah-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=works;Integrated Security=true;");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT firma FROM TestData 
                                  WHERE email = @email", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
      {
   //userName += dr["email"].ToString();
   //userName += dr["passwort"].ToString();
   userName += dr["firma"].ToString();
     }
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
    return userName;
        }



    }
}
```

Thanks for that help Guys

I have edited my Questions. Is that solution secure now? I mean against SQL-Injection. Is there something more what i can do better?

Comment: The first thing you're doing wrong is concatenating SQL strings.  You should use query parameters instead.

Comment: You should use parameterized SQL for this; your code as currently written is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.  I would make that change first; there's a chance the problem will go away when you do that.

Comment: You're also failing to put your SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataReader in `using` blocks, and you're using ASMX web services when you should be using WCF unless you have no choice.

Comment: @David can you help me a little? Iam new at this and i dont know how to use query parameters

Comment: @Bashud: http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2009/04/09/using-parameters-parameterized-queries-database-interactions-cshar-vbnet/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are calling  `LoginHelper.Login(passwort, email, firma);`

but in your method

`public static string Login(string email, string passwort, string firma)`

email is fist parameter.

actually in email parameter you have password, that's why it not return any result

change your `login` method in `LoginHelper` as below

```
public static string Login(string passwort, string email, string firma)
{
    string userName = "";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Yeah-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=works;Integrated Security=true;"))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT firma FROM TestData WHERE email = @email", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr["firma"]  != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    userName += rdr["firma"].ToString();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return userName;
}
```

Comment: Thx that was "One" of my Problems :)

Comment: @Bashud updated my answer with 'using' statements, sql parameters, null checks etc. hope it will help you..

Comment: Hey Damith i have a Question. Do i have to Close the connection or will that be done automatically?

Comment: You don't need to close it, it will handle automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If your email address contains an @ character, that may be your problem. The @ is a parameter marker for SQLCommand. It is going to think the latter part of your e-mail address is a sql parameter. You will need to pass the e-mail address using a parameter. That also protects you from SQL injection. Akatakritos's answer has an example of how to pass the email as a prameter.

Answer (score 1):

Also, for security and performance reasons, you should be using SqlParameters. Read up on SQL Injection attacks.

```
string userName = "";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Yeah-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=works;Integrated Security=true;");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT firma FROM TestData 
                                  WHERE email = @email" con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

con.Open();

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
   //userName += dr["email"].ToString();
   //userName += dr["passwort"].ToString();
   userName += dr["firma"].ToString();
}
dr.Close();
con.Close();
return userName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the other answer & comments.

> You have a security issue, if you're not going to use an ORM (Entity
>   Framework/NHibernate/etc...) please use parameterized queries

Solving your problem:

- Is data in your database?
- Are you pointing at the right database?
- Is your SQL correct?
- Is your SQL getting run?
- Run SQL Profiler and see what SQL is getting run, then test that in your SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing parameter in code try to use Sqlparameter to add parameter. It is best practice to use SQL parameter to add parametrs.
**You can also check the value of email by debugging....wether you are passing correct information.**

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT firma FROM TestData 
                              WHERE email = @email" conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);                     
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
            {                  
               userName += dr["firma"].ToString();

            }
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: the informations iam passing are correct, i already checked that. Damith posted the Solution

Comment: i could solved my Problem with the solution from Damith, but iam grateful for your help too :)